# Image in Alexa card response not showing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on Alexa skill and adding image in card's response. The image is not showing up on device but i can view it on simulator (screen shot attached).

What can be the possible reason? I enabled CORS on my S3 bucket, i am not sure if I did that properly. But before enabling that, the image was not available in simulator as well. How to check that?

[image]

Comment: I do run into this issue as well. Were you able to solve it? I have CORS enabled as suggested in the docs and by @justin-kovac. Of course I have read permissions enabled on the bucket itself as well as the different images within.

Comment: I found a solution - delete and reinstall the app under iOS. So it may be that the app simply has caching issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CORs policy was recently updated, so make sure yours reads as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://ask-ifr-download.s3.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://ask-ifr-download.s3.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same problem. I was running the Alexa app on Android. You need to clear your app cache. First, close the Alexa app. Then in Settings, open Apps, Amazon Alexa, Storage, Clear Cache.

Comment: Actually, I had the very same problem on iOS. First I thought it had been a badly configured CORS directive on S3 or missing read permissions. Once these were ruled out, the only thing left was to delete and re-install the app. Et voilá - the images started to appear. Obviously the app it not very... matured yet. I am using iOS btw.

Comment: Same issue for me with iOS. Reinstalling the app solved my issue! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CORS on your bucket, only make it publicly accessible (which you probably already did). Make sure you are using `https` to access it.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a problem with images not being shown.
In my case - images were not made public in the S3.
You can make images public in 3 steps:

1. open S3 and select file
2. click menu 'More'
3. click on 'Make public'

[image]